# Since I hit 2K rep, I no longer get reputation from edits. Is this intentional?

Tags: support, editing, reputation

The title basically sums it up. I just edited a question and while I'm not 100% sure that I didn't get +2 reputation from the edit - since I didn't look at my reputation count before, only after - my profile tab suggests that I didn't.

Is this behavior intentional? Will I get it in a little while?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, that bummed me out the first time I passed 2k on one of the sites too. Makes sense though, >2k is a well established user who no longer needs the tiny +2 of editing because their fascinating questions and incisive answers will soon catapult them to glorious heights.

Or something along those lines anyway.

Answer (score 7):

You get a reputation bonus for editing only when your edit is reviewed by other uses and approved. You don't get a reputation bonus when your edit is immediately taken into account with no one reviewing it.

At 2k reputation, you get the [privilege to edit questions and answers without supervision](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit). So you no longer get reputation from such edits.

At 20k reputation, you get the [privilege to edit tag wikis without supervision](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user). So you no longer get reputation from such edits.

Comment: This is the right explanation; for some reason it never gets explained this way. You get +2 for suggesting an edit that gets approved, and at 2k you're not suggesting post edits anymore, you're just making them

Answer (score 4):

Yup, that is only an enticement up to the 2k level, then it goes away. Here's the full info on it:

[Not getting edit's +2 rep after reaching 2k rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85229/not-getting-edits-2-rep-after-reaching-2k-rep)

Given you do a fair amount of editing on the site (I'm the one usually approving them) I hope you'll still continue with that behavior even w/o the reward of +2. It's appreciated and highly valued by many of us!!

Comment: huh, didn't realize I did that much editing.